# How to have access to global struct from another .cpp file?

Tags: c++, oop, class, struct, global

in Surface.h I have:

```
struct Surface{

    bool isAllowedOnTile[TILETYPE_COUNT];

    float moveBecomes;  // When this is 0, it is ignored
    float moveChange;   // Is ignored if moveBecomes is non-zero
    float affChange[ELEMENT_COUNT];

    ID2D1BitmapBrush* pBrush;
};
```

At some point, I need to initialize multiples surface like this:

```
Surface surface[SURFACEBMP_COUNT];

surface[0].moveBecomes = 123;
surface[0].moveChange = 0;
surface[0].affChange[0]= 2.0f;

...
```

Then I want to have access to surface[0], surface[1], surface[2]... from anywhere in my program. How do I do that?

Comment: The obvious solution is to make surface a global variable (global array to be precise). Whether that's a good solution is hard to say without seeing your code or understanding your program design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `extern`, and make `surface` global.

`file.h`

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H

...

extern Surface surface[SURFACEBMP_COUNT];

#endif
```

It's the header file, which you should include it where you need `surface`.

`file.cpp`

```
#include "file.h"

Surface surface[SURFACEBMP_COUNT];
```

Comment: Then, if anywhere in my program (inside any function of any .cpp file) I write, say, "surface[0].moveBecomes = 123", surface[0].moveBecomes will be 123 no matter from where I access it?

Comment: Yes, just include `file.h` and use it simply.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way - in header file use

```
extern Surface surface[SURFACEBMP_COUNT];
```

then declare and initialize it in .cpp file and use whenever you want.